# How to ask a user for the 3 RGB values (red, green, blue) and validate the entered values using an input mask?

Tags: batch-file

I want to ask the user of a batch file to set custom RGB color, e.g. `255,255,255`, preferably all stored in one environment variable.

I know that I can ask the question three times, check value is `GEQ 0` and `LEQ 255` and group them into a fourth variable in the right order with comma.

But surely there is a better way, isn't it?

What is the best way to ensure the user has entered color code correctly?

Like using an input mask `000,000,000`?

I'm vary new to batch file coding, worked out an awful lot from searching around although this has me stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
:: data entered ON command line?
SET "rgb=%*"
FOR %%a IN (anerror,rlevel,glevel,blevel) DO SET "%%a="
IF DEFINED rgb CALL :check %*&GOTO show
FOR %%a IN (rlevel,Red,glevel,Green,blevel,Blue) DO (
 IF DEFINED rgb (
  CALL :getlevel %%a
  IF DEFINED blevel GOTO show
  SET "rgb="
  ) ELSE SET "rgb=%%a"
 IF DEFINED anerror GOTO error

)
:show
IF DEFINED anerror GOTO error
IF NOT DEFINED blevel GOTO error
ECHO %rgb%
GOTO :EOF

:error
ECHO Invalid data found
SET "rgb="
GOTO :eof

:getlevel
SET /p "%rgb%=Level for %1 ? "
CALL :check %rlevel% %glevel% %blevel%
GOTO :eof

:check
SET "rlevel=%1"
SET "glevel=%2"
SET "blevel=%3"
CALL :validate %*
SET "rgb=%1,%2,%3"
GOTO :eof

:validate
SET "rgb=%1"
IF NOT DEFINED rgb GOTO :eof
IF "%rgb:~3%" neq "" GOTO seterr
SET "rgb=00%rgb%"
SET /a rgb=1%rgb:~-3% 2>NUL
IF %ERRORLEVEL% neq 0 GOTO seterr
IF %rgb% geq 1256 GOTO seterr
IF %rgb% lss 1000 GOTO seterr
shift&GOTO validate

:seterr
SET "anerror=y"
GOTO :eof
```

Interesting exercise.

My approach is to accumulate entries and check progressively.

`:check` sets the three values into `r/g/blevel` then validates each, rejecting too-long or out-of-range arguments by setting `anerror`.

In order to be valid, `anerror` must be clear and `blevel` must contain a value

Answer (score 1):

Instead of ensuring that *they have entered code correctly*, define and apply rules for transforming all out of range input to valid values, and possibly syntactic incorrect input to pre-defined default values, for instance as follows:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
    rem preset default values for particular colors
set /A _r=255
set /A _g=255
set /A _b=255
    rem build `_RGB` variable from particular colors
set "_RGB=%_r%,%_g%,%_b%"
    rem ask a user for input
set /P "_RGB=custom RGB color (enter a comma delimited list, default %_RGB%): "
    rem parse user's input
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=, " %%G in ("%_RGB%") do (
      rem compute particular colors so always come between 0 and 255
  2>NUL set /A _r=^( 1000%%~G %% 1000 ^) %% 256
  2>NUL set /A _g=^( 1000%%~H %% 1000 ^) %% 256
  2>NUL set /A _b=^( 1000%%~I %% 1000 ^) %% 256
)
    rem rebuild `_RGB` variable
set "_RGB=%_r%,%_g%,%_b%"
echo result %_RGB%
```

Tested for *weird* input combinations like `a,b,09` or `-1,-2,-3` or `0,xyz` etc. For instance, invalid `-1,-2,-3` triple results to (*surprising?*) `231,230,229`.

**Resources** (required reading, incomplete):

- (command reference) [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- (additional particularities) [Windows CMD Shell Command Line Syntax](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax.html)
- (`%~G` etc. special page) [Command Line arguments (Parameters)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-args.html)
- (`2>NUL` etc. special page) [Redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html)
- (`^(`, `^)` etc. special page) [Syntax : Escape Characters, Delimiters and Quotes](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-esc.html)

**Update**: added another approach allowing hexadecimal or octal input

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableExtensions
rem preset variables
set /A _r=255
set /A _g=255
set /A _b=255
rem build auxiliary `__RGB` variable from particular colors
set "__RGB=%_r%,%_g%,%_b%"

rem ask a user for input
set /P "__RGB=custom RGB color (enter a comma delimited list, default %__RGB%): "

rem parse user's input (updated `delims=,- `)
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=,- " %%G in ("%__RGB%") do (
  rem compute particular colors so always come between 0 and 255
  2>NUL set /A _r=^( 1000%%G %% 1000 ^) %% 256
  2>NUL set /A _g=^( 1000%%H %% 1000 ^) %% 256
  2>NUL set /A _b=^( 1000%%I %% 1000 ^) %% 256
)
rem rebuild `_RGB` variable
set "_RGB=%_r%,%_g%,%_b%"
echo 1st result %_RGB%

rem parse user's input - another approach 
rem allows hexadecimal or octal input e.g. 0xAA or 0252 for decimal 170   
for /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=, " %%G in ("%__RGB%") do (
  rem compute particular colors so always come between 0 and 255
  2>NUL set /A "_r=( %%G %% 256 + 16777216 ) %% 256"
  2>NUL set /A "_g=( %%H %% 256 + 16777216 ) %% 256"
  2>NUL set /A "_b=( %%I %% 256 + 16777216 ) %% 256"
)
rem rebuild `_RGB` variable
set "_RGB=%_r%,%_g%,%_b%"
echo 2nd result %_RGB%
```

Sample output:

```
==> D:\bat\SO\41178141.bat
custom RGB color (enter a comma delimited list, default 255,255,255): 0xAA, 0252, -100
1st result 255,252,100
2nd result 170,170,156

==>
```

Comment: thanks anyways, i didnt realise how handy it would be to enter one color at a time, limiting chances for error. this code works great although the code Magoo put up better suits my needs

Answer (score 1):

What about using [`findstr`](http://ss64.com/nt/findstr.html) to check for the input mask?

```bat
@echo off
:INPUT
set "RGB="
set /P RGB="Please enter an RGB colour value in the format '000,000,000': "
if defined RGB set "RGB=%RGB:"=""%
(echo("%RGB%"| findstr /R ^
    /C:"^\"[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"2[0-4][0-9]^,2[0-4][0-9]^,2[0-4][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"25[0-5]^,25[0-5]^,25[0-5]\"$" ^
 > nul) || goto :INPUT
```

This does not cover all combinations, of course, but it gives an idea of what I mean.

---

Just for the sake of completeness, here is the same code featuring all input mask combinations:

```bat
@echo off
:INPUT
set "RGB="
set /P RGB="Please enter an RGB colour value in the format '000,000,000': "
if defined RGB set "RGB=%RGB:"=""%
(echo("%RGB%"| findstr /R ^
    /C:"^\"[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,2[0-4][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,25[0-5]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,2[0-4][0-9]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,2[0-4][0-9]^,2[0-4][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,2[0-4][0-9]^,25[0-5]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,25[0-5]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,25[0-5]^,2[0-4][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,25[0-5]^,25[0-5]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"2[0-4][0-9]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"2[0-4][0-9]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,2[0-4][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"2[0-4][0-9]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,25[0-5]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"2[0-4][0-9]^,2[0-4][0-9]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"2[0-4][0-9]^,2[0-4][0-9]^,2[0-4][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"2[0-4][0-9]^,2[0-4][0-9]^,25[0-5]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"2[0-4][0-9]^,25[0-5]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"2[0-4][0-9]^,25[0-5]^,2[0-4][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"2[0-4][0-9]^,25[0-5]^,25[0-5]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"25[0-5]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"25[0-5]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,2[0-4][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"25[0-5]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]^,25[0-5]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"25[0-5]^,2[0-4][0-9]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"25[0-5]^,2[0-4][0-9]^,2[0-4][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"25[0-5]^,2[0-4][0-9]^,25[0-5]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"25[0-5]^,25[0-5]^,[0-1][0-9][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"25[0-5]^,25[0-5]^,2[0-4][0-9]\"$" ^
    /C:"^\"25[0-5]^,25[0-5]^,25[0-5]\"$" ^
 > nul) || goto :INPUT
```

Comment: thanks anyway mate, to be honest im very new at coding and cant get my head around findstr, some others posted full working code i got to work